# React redux dispatch issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, dispatch

I'm trying to dispatch a function from a component which has route 'localhost:8080/location/:id' but it seems to give an error, the same dispatch function is working in other component which doesn't have param id.

This is error i'm getting while dispatching that action.

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _bandwidth2.default) is not a function

This is my dispatchToProps.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addBandwidth: (bandwidth) => dispatch(addBandwidth(bandwidth))
  });

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(UpgradeBandwidth);
```

This is my action.

```
export const addBandwidth = (bandwidth) => ({
  type: 'ADD_BANDWIDTH',
  bandwidth
});
```

Just to clarify, this function working in other component but not in one which has param id in its route. Please help. Thanks.

This is where i called.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
    this.props.addBandwidth({
        _id: uuid(),
        leasedCircuitId: this.state.leasedCircuitId,
        bandwidth: this.state.bandwidth,
        bandwidthUnit: this.state.bandwidthUnit,
        bandwidthType: this.state.bandwidthType,
        lastMile: this.state.lastMile,
        remarks: this.state.remarks,
        discountPolicy: this.state.discountPolicy,
        status: false
      });
  }
```

Comment: how did you use `addBandwidth`

Comment: this.props.addBandwidth({ myObject })

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem in that declaration. Maybe you want to share the line where the error occurs, or some place where `bandwidth2` is.

Comment: The problem is not in the declaration, is in the usage of `addBandwidth`, check all the places where is called.

Comment: the error occurred right where this line => addBandwidth: (bandwidth) => dispatch(addBandwidth(bandwidth))

Comment: Check the imports on that component, verify that you're importing `addBandwith` in the right way.

Comment: i checked, it's the right way

Comment: @EdwinVargas,  you were right i was importing it in wrong way, now its working just fine, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, the `.default` in this part of the error message: `(0 , _bandwidth2.default)` maybe indicates a wrong import.

Comment: @RahulKumar  The error message means that you use `bandWidth` as a function.
if `bandWidth` should be a function, `this.props.addBandWidth({ myObject })` is wrong. if `bandWidth` should be a object, check whether called `bandWidth` like `bandWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

Check your App.js
Are you shure you imported addBandwidth()?

`import { addBandwidth } from 'path to your action'`